# Size Chart that can convert IN to CM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I'm a beginner and I'd like to create a size chart table that can convert it's metric.
**Ie.** The table data has values in "inches" I would like it to convert to "centimetres" when a button is pressed. Some of the table data's inner html is written like " *1 - 2"* ". I'd like both the numbers to be converted cm values, while keeping the "-" in between. The table data should also be able to convert back to it's original metric.

This is how far I got. I wasn't able to figure out how to convert the numbers.

https://jsfiddle.net/zajwgp5r/

```js
$(document).on('click', ' #change', function(e) {
  if ($('#converted').is(':checked')) {
    $('#data td').html($('#data td').html().replaceAll('"', 'cm'));
    $('#change').html('Display in inches');
    $('#converted').prop('checked', false);
    alert("converting to cm");
  } else {
    $('#data td').html($('#data td').html().replaceAll('cm', '"'));
    $('#converted').prop('checked', true);
    $('#change').html('Display in centimeters');
    alert("converting to in");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="change">Display in centimeters</button>

<input type="radio" id="converted" checked="">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Size</th>
      <th>XS</th>
      <th>S</th>
      <th>M</th>
      <th>L</th>
      <th>XL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data">
    <tr>
      <th>CHEST</th>
      <td>32 - 34"</td>
      <td>35 - 37"</td>
      <td>38 - 40"</td>
      <td>41 - 43" </td>
      <td>44 - 46"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>WAIST</th>
      <td>26 - 28"</td>
      <td>29 - 31"</td>
      <td>32 - 34"</td>
      <td>35 - 37"</td>
      <td>38 - 40"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>SEAT / HIP</th>
      <td>32 - 34"</td>
      <td>35 - 37"</td>
      <td>38 - 40"</td>
      <td>41 - 43"</td>
      <td>44 - 46"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>SLEEVE</th>
      <td>24.8"</td>
      <td>25.1"</td>
      <td>25.6"</td>
      <td>26"</td>
      <td>26.4"</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Instead of parsing a range of numbers, why not make the range out of two different elements that each have an individual number in them?  *E.g.*, instead of `<td>35 - 37"</td>` use `<td><span class="start">35</span> - <span class="end">37</span>"</td>` or something like that. Then all you need to do is convert the number (after converting string to number) and not have to deal with parsing the range. When you click your button, you'll need to do `.each` on your class members to do the conversions and reference 'self' to set the new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having to parse the individual strings, why not just wrap each number you want to convert in something that's easy to select? In this case, I put each number in a span. Then it's as easy as

```
$("#data span").each( //Convert the numbers here );
```

Parse the HTML inside each span into a float, then multiply or divide by 2.54 to convert between in and cm.

```
$("#data span").each(function(){
  $(this).html(parseFloat($(this).html()) * 2.54);
});
```

Finally, your unit conversion is a bit broken. You're applying the conversion of the first element to all elements. Use `.each()` to parse each one individually.

```
$("#data td").each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).html().replaceAll('"', "cm"));
});
```

You may also want to put rules on how the numbers are put back into the HTML. `Math.round` or `.toFixed(length)` would be helpful for that. Since this is floating point math, it's slightly inaccurate and you'll get things like `26.0000000004` when you convert.

```js
$(document).on('click', ' #change', function(e) {
  if($('#converted').is(':checked')) {
    $("#data span").each(function(){
      $(this).html(parseFloat($(this).html()) * 2.54);
    });
    $("#data td").each(function(){
      $(this).html($(this).html().replaceAll('"', "cm"));
    });
    $('#change').html('Display in inches');
    $('#converted').prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    $("#data span").each(function(){
      $(this).html(parseFloat($(this).html()) / 2.54);
    });
    $("#data td").each(function(){
      $(this).html($(this).html().replaceAll('cm', '"'));
    });
    $('#converted').prop('checked', true);
    $('#change').html('Display in centimeters');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<button type="button" id="change">
Display in centimeters
</button>

<input type="radio" id="converted" checked="">
<table>
  <thead>
<tr>
<th> Size</th>
<th>XS</th>
<th>S</th>
<th>M</th>
<th>L</th>
<th>XL</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody id="data">
<tr>
  <th>CHEST</th>
  <td><span>32</span> - <span>34</span>"</td>
  <td><span>35</span> - <span>37</span>"</td>
  <td><span>38</span> - <span>40</span>"</td>
  <td><span>41</span> - <span>43</span>" </td>
  <td><span>44</span> - <span>46</span>"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>WAIST</th>
  <td><span>26</span> - <span>28</span>"</td>
  <td><span>29</span> - <span>31</span>"</td>
  <td><span>32</span> - <span>34</span>"</td>
  <td><span>35</span> - <span>37</span>"</td>
  <td><span>38</span> - <span>40</span>"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>SEAT / HIP</th>
  <td><span>32</span> - <span>34</span>"</td>
  <td><span>35</span> - <span>37</span>"</td>
  <td><span>38</span> - <span>40</span>"</td>
  <td><span>41</span> - <span>43</span>"</td>
  <td><span>44</span> - <span>46</span>"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>SLEEVE</th>
  <td><span>24.8</span>"</td>
  <td><span>25.1</span>"</td>
  <td><span>25.6</span>"</td>
  <td><span>26</span>"</td>
  <td><span>26.4</span>"</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: ur right just make sure to have `Number.toPrecision` or `Number.toFixed` so that those huge numbers don't show

Comment: thank you so much @David 

I did as you said and added a rule to round the number by adding this at the bottom.

   $("#data span").each(function(){
    $(this).html(parseFloat($(this).html()).toFixed(0));
   });